# Get images' drawable addresses from the gallery and store them inside an array

Tags: java, android

I want to get images from the gallery, get their drawable addresses and then store those addresses in an int array. The users are allowed to choose the images. I have used an `ImageView` and the user is allowed to select an image from the list.

```
public class StickerSelectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

  public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_ID = "extra_sticker_id";

    private final int[] stickerIds = {
            R.drawable.abra,
            R.drawable.bellsprout,
            R.drawable.bracelet,
            R.drawable.bullbasaur,
            R.drawable.camera,
            R.drawable.candy 
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_sticker_activity);

        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.stickers_recycler_view);
        GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);

        List<Integer> stickers = new ArrayList<>(stickerIds.length);
        for (Integer id : stickerIds) {
            stickers.add(id);
        }

        recyclerView.setAdapter(new StickersAdapter(stickers, this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onStickerSelected(int stickerId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_ID, stickerId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }

    class StickersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StickersAdapter.StickerViewHolder> {

        private final List<Integer> stickerIds;
        private final Context context;
        private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        StickersAdapter(@NonNull List<Integer> stickerIds, @NonNull Context context) {
            this.stickerIds = stickerIds;
            this.context = context;
            this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public StickerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new StickerViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sticker_item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(StickerViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, getItem(position)));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return stickerIds.size();
        }

        private int getItem(int position) {
            return stickerIds.get(position);
        }

        class StickerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            ImageView image;

            StickerViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sticker_image);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (pos >= 0) { // might be NO_POSITION
                            onStickerSelected(getItem(pos));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

to select the images

```
   gal_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select 
                     Picture"), 1000);

                }
            });
  @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {

            // Get the Image from data

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            imagesUriList = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            if (data.getData() != null) {

                Uri mImageUri = data.getData();

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imageURI = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                selected_file.add(getPath(getActivity(), mImageUri));  //store into array

            }
```